# Sum a column from a sum

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I am looking for a way to sum another amount from a summed column from within a SQL script.

Making a simpler script

```
   SELECT c.customerName, b.bankName, sum(1) as ExceptionCount
    FROM  customer c INNER JOIN bank b on c.customerBranchId = 
b.branchId
    INNER JOIN  exception e ON c.customerId = e.exceptionId
    GROUP BY b.bankName, customerName
    ORDER BY b.bankName, customerName
```

So if I run this and my results are something like:

```
BOB     bank1       17
Sue     bank2       8
Steve   bank3       12
```

What I am looking for is another column on this to SUM the exceptions by the CustomerName so it translates into

```
BOB bank1   17  3  <-- This is the exceptionCount By CustomerName   
Sue bank2   8   2   (that's what I am looking for)
Steve   bank3   12  4
```

Comment: Perhaps try and reduce the problem to a simpler, more general sql statement first.

Comment: Exceptions are joined to loan, so if you want to group by customer name only, simply `GROUP BY c.customerId, c.customerName, c.customerNumber`. And you could use `count(*)` instead of `sum(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT b.bankId, b.bankName, c.customerId, c.customerName, c.customerNumber,
count(*) exceptionCount
FROM
 exception AS ex INNER JOIN exceptionDefinition AS ed
  ON ex.exceptionDefId=ed.exceptionDefId
 INNER JOIN customer AS c ON c.customerId=ex.customerId
 INNER JOIN bank AS b ON c.bankId=b.bankId
 LEFT OUTER JOIN loan AS l ON ex.loanId=l.loanId
 LEFT OUTER JOIN collateral AS cl ON cl.collateralLoanId=l.loanId
 LEFT OUTER JOIN exceptedDocument AS exdoc ON 
exdoc.exceptionId=ex.exceptionId
WHERE
 ex.statusType = 'required'
 AND ((ed.computationType = 'manual' AND ex.exceptionState <> 'N')
OR(ed.computationType ='computed' AND exdoc.documentExceptionState > 'N') )
 GROUP BY
 b.bankId, b.bankName, c.customerId, c.customerName, c.customerNumber
ORDER BY
 b.bankName,
 c.customerName,
 l.loanNumber
```

If the outer joins return many rows, you might want to do a `count(distinct ex.exceptionId)`

Comment: This looks all right and yes the count() works but its the same issue as before which is a Sum of those counts by CustomerName or customerId.  The original scope was a sum of a sum or an aggregate on an aggregate.  So another column on this dataset which is literally SUM(exceptionCount) by customerId

Comment: i'm not sure what you're looking for.  `Sam 12, Dave 9, Richard 20` or something else?

Comment: post you new sql and output

Comment: oh no - i'm even more confused.  what do the `3,2,4` values represent?

Comment: what you're demonstrating is exceptions by person, what's the other discriminator?